# Javascript selecting and comparing checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

title of this question seems to be pretty bad, I am sincerely sorry for that. I just couldn't come up with better phrasing.

I am trying to work on a "webapp" which allows the user to experiment with the logical operators like XOR, NOR and AND on a webpage. I am struggling with the programming though, especially with the NOR operator - which only works, if neither of my two checkboxes are checked.

```js
iif ($("#norA").prop("checked") || $("#norB").prop("checked"))  {  
  $("#nors").html("off");} 
  {$("#nors").html("on");}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="options">
<div class="col-md-2"><div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="nor" id="norA">A</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="nor" id="norB">B</label>
      </div></div>

<div class="row" id="result">
  <div class="col-md-2"><p id="nors">on</p></div></div> <!--placeholder of the solution/output -->
```

Comment: Oh boy, I messed my formatation. I am sorry, I am currently on my notebook and lost track of everything on the screen.

Comment: `$("#norA").prop("checked", false)` - that **sets** the "checked" property to `false`. You want `!$("#norA").prop("checked")` to **test** whether it's `false`.

Comment: Thanks Pointy, I will test it out immediately! I read that 'false' thingy on the internet..

Comment: I tried to edit it, but I probably made another mistake since it is not working yet.

Comment: I should have been more clear: `$("#norA").prop("checked")` fetches the value of the property. The value will be either `true` or `false`. If you want to find out if the value is `false`, you need `!$("#norA").prop("checked")` - that leading `!` is important.

Comment: Allright, gotcha! It is still not working for me. I am really unsure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will handle the input and select the correct `nor` condition.  Note that by separating the functional code from the event handler, you can also use it to set the initial condition, which this does.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:checkbox").change(function() {
        toggleNors();
    });
    toggleNors();
})

function toggleNors() {
    var nor = !$("#norA").is(":checked") && !$("#norB").is(":checked")
    $("#nors").text(nor ? "on" : "off");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="options">
    <div class="col-md-2"><div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="nor" id="norA">A</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="nor" id="norB">B</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="result">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <p id="nors">on</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The [`nor` truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_NOR#Truth_table) is true if, and only if, neither `a` nor `b` are checked, and that's how this is implemented.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks a lot. I would never come up with such a use of toggleNors().

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
if (!($("#norA").is(":checked") && $("#norB").is(":checked")))  {      $("#nors").html("on");}
else {$("#nors").html("off");}
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="options">
<div class="col-md-2"><div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="nor" id="norA">A</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="nor" id="norB">B</label>
      </div></div>


<div class="row" id="result">
  <div class="col-md-2"><p id="nors">on</p></div></div>
```

Comment: Thank ou a lot for your work! You were the first one and I learnt a lot from this. Thanks again! Had to be off though hehe. It is so nice to see the different approaches, especially you and Michael made.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if($("#norA").is(":checked") && $("#norB").is(":checked")){
    $("#nors").html("off");
        }
 else{ 
   $("#nors").html("on");
       }
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for your help! Really helped me out.